# Is it possible to geocode an entire street?

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I want to use the geocoding api to obtain a list of all lat/lng co-ordinates in a certain street. For example my query input may be Oxford Street, London and my desired output would be all lat/lng points within Oxford Street.

Comment: I'm afraid the Geocoding API was designed for different purpose. It's just converts address to coordinate (forward geoocoding) and latlng to address (reverse geocoding).

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Are you aware of any service that could help with this?